# What is $H^{*-n}(M)$?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, manifolds

I'm reading [Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387906134) by Bott and Tu and I'm a little confused about the notation $H^{*-n}(M)$.  I don't see a definition of this listed anywhere in the text, though I can sort of infer from context what's meant by the notation.

- I know that $H^k(M)$ is the $k$th cohomology class on $M$ (equivalence class of $k$-forms).
- I know too that $H^*(M)$ is the direct sum of all cohomology classes (i.e. $\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty H^i(M)$ ).
- The first place in the text I can recall seeing this notation (or similar notation) is when they talk about the Poincar${\acute {e}}$ Lemma where they state an isomorphism $H_c^{*+1}(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^1) \simeq H_c^*(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  My guess here is that it has to do with how the dimensions of the forms get mapped to cohomology classes of different spaces (i.e. in this example stated, since $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^1$ is essentially the same as $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, the isomorphism is somehow stating that $H_c^k(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^1) \simeq H_c^{k-1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?
- This notation is also used too in the context of vector bundles.  If $\pi:E\to M$ is a rank-$n$ vector bundle on a manifold $M$ of dimension $k$, then Bott and Tu have stated that $H_{cv}^*(E) \simeq H^{*-n}(M)$ where the $cv$-distinction is for forms of compact vertical support.  Is this to indicate that a compact-vertically supported $l$-form gets naturally sent to an $l-n$ form on $M$ via the projection $\pi_*$?

I may have just answered my own question, but I'm self-studying and it would be nice to have verification.

Comment: I think it means something like $H^i(E) \cong H^{i-n}(M)$ for all $i$ where this makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This community wiki solution is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue.

In fact is is not unusual to write $H^*(M) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty H^i(M)$. Then
$$H^{*-n}(M) = \bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty G_i$$
where $G_i = 0$ for $i = 0,\ldots,n-1$ and $G_i = H^{i-n}(M)$ for $i \ge n$. Roughly speaking, this gives a new grading to $H^*(M)$.

As user113102 comments, it is simpler to regard $*$ as a variable. You could also write $i, m$ or something else instead of $*$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I suppose it is more straightforward to say something of the form "$H^k(E) \simeq H^{k-n}(M)$ for all $k=n, n+1, \ldots$"?

Comment: That is correct!